# Problem with state in react hooks while using firebase-firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm not sure why but for some reason I don't have the value of old state when calling update, it always seems to have the value of default state.

```
const defaultState:RootState = {
    loadSessions:(groupId:string,lectureId:string)=>{},
    loadSession:(sessionId:string)=>()=>{},
    userJoined:(user:IUser)=>{}
};

const TSessionContext = React.createContext<RootState>(defaultState);

export const TSessionProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<RootState>(defaultState);

    const loadSession = (sessionId:string)=>{
        console.info("Calling load session");
        const unsubSession = db.collection(COLLECTION_REF).doc(sessionId)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const session = snapshot.data() as ISession;
                console.info("setting session",state);
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    session
                });
            });

        const unsubUsers = db.collection(`${COLLECTION_REF}/${sessionId}/users`)
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const users:IUser[] = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    users.push(doc.data() as IUser)
                });
                console.info("setting users",state);
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    users
                });
            });

        return ()=>{
            unsubUsers();
            unsubSession();
        };
    }

    return (
        <TSessionContext.Provider
            value={{
                ...state,
                loadSession,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </TSessionContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useTSession = () =>  useContext(TSessionContext);
```

Here I always get output "setting session" with default state value and "setting users" with default state value.

Code where I am using this hook:

```
const {loadSession,session,users} = useTSession();
    
useEffect(()=>{
  if(sessionId&&!session){
    const unsub = loadSession(sessionId);
    return () => {
      unsub()
    }
  }
},[]);
```

Then in my main component I get `session` first with `user` undefined.
And then `user` with `session` undefined.

If I add another hook that fetches more data, then it has the same issue. So I'm really not sure what is the problem here.

If I split my hooks internal state like this:

```
const [iSession, setISession] = useState<any>();
const [iUser, setIUser] = useState<any>();

return (
    <TSessionContext.Provider
        value={{
            ...state,
            users:iUser,
            session:iSession,
            loadSession,
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </TSessionContext.Provider>
);
```

Then it seems to work correctly, not sure why the other variant doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous so when you call them like that you are overwriting the previous state. I haven't seen a pattern like the one you are using but you shouldn't try write state twice in the same function as you will face problems you could maybe update to this

```
const loadSession = async(sessionId:string)=>{
        const newState = {}
        console.info("Calling load session");
        const unsubSession = await db.collection(COLLECTION_REF).doc(sessionId)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const session = snapshot.data() as ISession;
                console.info("setting session",state);
                newState.session = session
            });

        const unsubUsers = await db.collection(`${COLLECTION_REF}/${sessionId}/users`)
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const users:IUser[] = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    users.push(doc.data() as IUser)
                });
                console.info("setting users",state);
                newState.users = users
            });
            setState({
              ...state,
              ...newState,
           });

        return ()=>{
            unsubUsers();
            unsubSession();
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, but onSnapshot is async as well. So in this case there might be a chance that users collection is fetched before session. Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes you are right, make func async and add await, sorry missed that

Comment: another simpler answer is to split state
have
const [session, setSession] = useState(null)
const [users, setUsers] = useState(null)

That way you dont have to worry

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked. I just wanted to understand why the version with one state doesn't work.

Comment: its because its async so the the ...state looks at the current state before the the function starts so the second to complete will overright the first completed.  I hope my original answer explained that properly